# Can I pull data from an existingAzure Storage Account table using ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-table-storage

I have an existing Azure Storage Account which has a table. This table has a few details that I would be needing to use in my mainTemplate.json ARM file. Can I pull these values directly in the ARM Template.

```
[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',parameters('storageAccountName'))).primaryEndpoints.table, parameters('tableName'))]
```

I have been using the above statement in the outputs section and it returns me the table uri. Can I get the values inside that table by any way?

Comment: Not out of the box. You could look into deployment scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Silent By referring this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI)

Try with  using  **DeploymentScriptOutputs**

The script takes one parameter, and output the parameter value. DeploymentScriptOutputs is used for storing outputs.
example

```
"outputs": {
    "result": {
      "value": "[reference('runPowerShellInlineWithOutput').outputs.text]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

In the outputs section, the value line shows how to access the stored values. Write-Output is used for debugging purpose. To learn how to access the output file, see [Monitor and troubleshoot deployment scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI#monitor-and-troubleshoot-deployment-scripts)

Thank you [@silent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537195/silent) for your suggestion